# Custom collider?

Tags: swift

So I have a blue block in my game. I have a square that moves right and when I touch the screen it jumps.

This is my block:

[image]

It is blue and the black parts should be the colliders. So the question is if I can do the following: I want my square to be destroyed only when it hits the black parts, if it passes through the blue part it will not be destroyed. Is it a method to do this custom collider? The black parts won't be visible in my game. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a Swift question, is it? Are you looking for an algorithm to calculate object overlaps?

Comment: I am looking for a Swift method to do this collider, I haven't found yet anything...

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible ...

Comment: Sure it's possible. You have to calculate the position of your block and compare whether it overlaps with your black parts positions. Use `NSRect.intersects(<#rect: CGRect#>)` to find that out.